# How to include struct in to-be-exported class in dll?

Tags: c++, class, dll, struct

I'm trying to write a back-end in cpp, which can read binary files of quiz questions and only display the answers when asked. I want to use DLL-linking and followed the Microsoft's walkthrough at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235636.aspx which does not use class members. I would like to export them as well, and also include certain structs in the class.

Basically, I want to be able to declare and use objects of the class and use its member functions just by including the DLL in any further project I undertake. How do I go about this? In my following code,

```
#ifdef CXWDLL_EXPORTS
#define CXWAPI __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define CXWAPI __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include<string>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long long UINT64
#define SIZE 15
#define GRIDSIZE 225
#define MAXCLUES 50

namespace cxw
{
    class CXWAPI CXWPuzzle
    {
        public:
            CXWPuzzle();
            virtual ~CXWPuzzle();
            struct Header
            {
                string signature;
                string version;
                short type;
            } header;
            struct Checksum
            {
                int header;
                int crossie;
                int grid;
                int clues;
                int solution;
                int file;
            } checksum;
            struct Contents
            {
                struct CHeader
                {
                    string title;
                    string author;
                    string copyright;
                    string notes;
                } cHeader;
                struct Grid
                {
                    short size;
                    UINT64 grid[4];
                    char filled[GRIDSIZE];
                    UINT64 filled[4];
                } grid;
                struct Clues
                {
                    string across[MAXCLUES];
                    string down[MAXCLUES];
                } clues;
                struct Solution
                {
                    char answers[GRIDSIZE];
                    string across[MAXCLUES];
                    string down[MAXCLUES];
                } solution;
            } contents;
    };
}
```

the VS 2010 compiler says "Error: Expected a declaration", at:

```
} solution;
```

and subsequent closing brackets. I'm yet to add the methods of the class.

What am I doing wrong? Also, will my code let me do what I have mentioned as my requirement?

Comment: I don't get it. Your structs only exist in a header file. Can't you just include the header file?

Comment: I could, but I'm trying to export this as a DLL to be used for distribution. Anyway, I still don't understand the errors, which is the cause of the question.

Comment: The errors are because you haven't included the header file. I'm afraid you are going to have to distribute the DLL and the header file.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. The contents of the header file are what I've posted, in which I get the above-mentioned error.

Comment: My apologies, I thought your second code extract was in a different file from your first code extract. See answer below

Comment: So now you've radically changed the code you originally posted. That is annoying. How do you expect to get meaningful answers when you only post an approximation to the code you were actually having trouble with.

Comment: The latest code still has the error I pointed out below, plus a new one that has nothing at all to do with the errors you say you are getting. I have no confidence that the code I am looking at is the code you are working with. Cut and paste the real code into the question above.

Comment: That is the real code. The code I was working with posted errors, so I tried moving the struct definitions inside the class definition. And I posted that new code, in which I still had errors. The error "Error: Expected a declaration" appears at the the last four lines of code, at every closing bracket that I've used.

Comment: Please don't remove existing code which is referred to in comments or answers. Add new code if you want to make an edit. Your code above (at the time of writing) still has the error of `filled` being redeclared and the missing semi colon in the typedef. Also the line where you say you are getting the error `}, solution;` does not appear in the code above. In the code you have `} solution;` not `}, solution;` This might give you a clue.

Comment: I'm utterly sorry. The "filled" error was the error I was looking for in the structs. And the line I have mis-referred is the line I re-typed, instead of doing a copy-paste, which I edited again. Utterly sorry for being a bad asker. Thanks for the resolution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Grid
{
    short size;
    UINT64 grid[4];
    char filled[225];
    UINT64 filled[4];
};
```

You have one error here, `filled` has been declared twice. When I fix that I can't reproduce the other errors you say you get.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it. Still, I'm getting various other errors, like "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'namespace'"

Comment: And I still have the said "Error: Expected a declaration" error at the specified line.

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai That's because you are missing a semi colon `typedef unsigned long long UINT64` should be `typedef unsigned long long UINT64;`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm really sorry for changing the code between answers.

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai OK well I think we got there in the end. Apologies again for misreading your original question.